# Objective-C : fail in if statement

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have this code in one of the functions in my app :

```
int count = [songsArray count];
if (count - 1 > index) {
     //blablabla
}
```

And i found that this line :

```
if (count - 1 > index) {
```

Crash my application with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JKDictionary idStr]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1929b990'
```

index is also int . Any idea what can be the problem?

## Edit

I tried this code too:

```
int count = [songsArray count] - 1;
int indexTmp = index;

if (count > indexTmp) {

}
```

In the debugger i can see that count is 99 and indexTmp is 99 too

Comment: Are you sure that this exemption is in this line of code? Add NSLog statements before the if statement and see what kind of classes the count and int are.

Comment: This `[JKDictionary idStr]` suggest that the `if` statement is not your issue, on the `if` statement I think it should be `if ((count - 1) > index)`

Comment: I edit me post with more details

Comment: JKDictionary also potentially suggest the use of JSON.  where are you defining `songsArray`, what type is it, etc...?

Comment: That's not very helpful @MatthiasBauch

Comment: Make sure `JKDictionary` implements `idStr`(static) function.

Comment: JK is a prefix used with JSONKit @trumpetlicks, well observed

Comment: @trumpetlicks songsArray is NSArray

Comment: Apart from sbarow noticing the real reason for the crash (a message named idStr being sent to an object of type JKDictionary): The comparison "if (count - 1 > index)" is just upside down. It's very jarring and destroys the flow of reading your code. It seems you are checking that "index" is inside songsArray and not the index of the last element of that array. if (count > 0 && index < count - 1) handles the extreme case of an empty array, and then checks precisely for what you want to check: That the index is before the last array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that you tried to call

```
-[JKDictionary idStr]
```

and there is no method or instance variable named idStr in the object JKDictionary.
This has obviously nothing to do with the code you posted. And don't get confused by the line

```
int count = [songsArray count];
```

Someone wrote that you used the variable count before you declared it, but that is wrong. [songsArray count] returns the number of elements in the songsArray. That has nothing to do with the declaration of the integer variable named count. The posted code is ok.

Comment: I don't know how but from what you wrote here i found the problem in my code.Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using a pre compiled binary of JSONKit.

You need to add this to your "other linker flags" in the build settings section:

```
-all_load
```